# INSERT INTO from SELECT: The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, insert-into

I am still getting a weird error:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Code:

```
    INSERT INTO @tab (Phone)
    select t2.Phone 
    from 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT top 999 t3.Phone, MIN(t3.Ord) 
      FROM 
      (
        select Phone1 as Phone, Ord from @tabTemp
        union all
        select Phone2 as Phone, Ord from @tabTemp
      ) t3 
      GROUP BY t3.Phone 
      ORDER BY MIN(t3.Ord) asc, t3.Phone
    ) t2
```

The idea is to select all phone numbers from @tabTemp with their row order. Then I wanna distinct them and insert distincted numbers into table @tab. *Top 999* is here only for *order by* purpose, because I use it into a *function* (UDF).

Structures are following:

```
    declare @tabTemp TABLE 
    (
    Phone1 varchar(128) NULL,
    Phone2 varchar(128) NULL,
    Ord int
    );

    declate @tab TABLE 
    (
    Phone varchar(max) NULL
    );
```

**EDITED:**

**FULL CODE**

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myFnc(@PID int, @VID int, @JID int, @ColumnNo int)
      RETURNS @tab TABLE 
      (
          Phone varchar(max) NULL
      )
      AS 
      BEGIN
        if @PID is null and @VID is null and @JID is null 
          return;

        if @ColumnNo is null or (@ColumnNo<>2 and @ColumnNo<>3 and @ColumnNo<>6)
          return;

        declare @catH int;
        set @catH = dbo.fncGetCategoryID('H','tt');   -- just returning int value       
        declare @kvalP int;
        set @kvalP = dbo.fncGetCategoryID('P','te');          
        declare @kvalR int;
        set @kvalR = dbo.fncGetCategoryID('R','te');

        declare @tabTemp TABLE 
        (
          Phone1 varchar(128) NULL,
          Phone2 varchar(128) NULL,
          Ord int
        );

        -- finding parent subject + current one
        WITH subj AS(
                SELECT  *
                FROM    Subjekt
                WHERE   
                  (ID = @PID and @PID is not null)
                  or
                  (ID = @VID and @VID is not null)
                  or
                  (ID = @JID and @JID is not null)            
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  t.*
                FROM    Subjekt t 
                      INNER JOIN subj r ON r.ID = t.ID
        )

        INSERT INTO @tabTemp (Phone1,Phone2)
          (select 
              (case when o.TYP1=@catH then o.TEL1 else null end) Phone1
              ,(case when o.TYP2=@catH then o.TEL2 else null end) Phone2
              ,so.POR_C
          from 
              subj s
              ,SubjektPerson so
              ,Persons o
              ,recSetup idS              
              ,recSetup idSO
              ,recSetup idO            
          where 1=1
              and idO.isValid=1
              and idSO.isValid=1
              and idS.isValid=1
              and idSO.ID0=so.ID
              and idS.ID0=s.ID
              and idO.ID0=o.ID

              and so.ID_PERSON=o.ID
              and so.ID_SUBJECT=s.ID

              and (o.TYP=@kvalP or o.TYP=@kvalR)

          ) 

          INSERT INTO @tab (Phone)
              select t2.Phone 
              from 
              (
                SELECT DISTINCT top 999 t3.Phone, MIN(t3.Ord) 
                FROM 
                (
                  select Phone1 as Phone, Ord from @tabTemp
                  union all
                  select Phone2 as Phone, Ord from @tabTemp
                ) t3 
                GROUP BY t3.Phone 
                ORDER BY MIN(t3.Ord) asc, t3.Phone
              ) t2

        RETURN
      END
```

Comment: Do you have any triggers on your tables?

Comment: @podiluska these are table variables so any triggers aren't on these.

Comment: @SeanLange or this could just be an example and not the real tables...

Comment: they are just table variables. So no triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've focussed on the wrong insert. This is the one with the mismatch:

```
    INSERT INTO @tabTemp (Phone1,Phone2)
      (select 
          (case when o.TYP1=@catH then o.TEL1 else null end) Phone1
          ,(case when o.TYP2=@catH then o.TEL2 else null end) Phone2
          ,so.POR_C
      from 
          ...
```

Two columns in the insert list, 3 columns in the subselect. I can't tell just from the naming whether `POR_C` was meant to end up in the `Ord` column or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have distinct AND a group by on the same query. You could greatly simplify this.

```
INSERT INTO @tab (Phone)
SELECT top 999 t3.Phone
FROM 
(
    select Phone1 as Phone, Ord from @tabTemp
    union all
    select Phone2 as Phone, Ord from @tabTemp
) t3 
GROUP BY t3.Phone 
ORDER BY MIN(t3.Ord) asc, t3.Phone
```

Now for the error message you were receiving, it doesn't seem like it came from this block of code because the syntax is fine and the number of columns matches correctly. I suspect the error is somewhere earlier in your code.

Also, you might want to consider using temp tables instead of table variables since it seems like you have a lot of rows in these tables.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface, it appears you are maybe triggering a query planner bug or something.  There are a number of *iffy* things going on:

- The **union all** of the same table to itself
- Using both **group by** and **distinct**

I'm not sure what you mean by

> Top 999 is here only for order by purpose, because I use it into a function (UDF).

Do you mean this whole query is executed within a UDF?  If so, are there other queries that might be giving that error?

Comment: **Union all** is here because of selecting two different columns (Phone1 and Phone1) into separed rows